# File path of .exe File in windows 7

Tags: c++, file, command-prompt, filepath

I am working in a C++ project. I need to obtain the path of a installed software. (Eg. skype.exe) Is there any way to find the path via C++ coding or via Widows command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you are needing it for, and how generic you want it.

1. You can use [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the PATH variable, and search these paths.
2. You can use the App Paths registry key, as Gabe says. [See also...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. Usually there are pretty clear application-specific ways to find the path via the registry. Either via the HKLM/Software key or [Uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Careful with localization and hard-coding application names...
4. If you are just trying to launch the app, ShellExecute doesn't need the full path, it works almost like the "run" dialog box in the start menu.

Comment: there is the `getenv` function, if that's what you mean. But obviously there are no registry access functions or platform-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the `App Paths` registry key. For `skype.exe` you would look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\skype.exe`

You can call the standard Win32 API [`RegQueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724909.aspx) to read it.

Comment: Well yes - you can use C++ to query the registry keys suggested to you. You can also write a method in C++ to search the common locations for apps in a given OS. If your question is, does C++ provide a standard library to find installed software on my operating system, the answer is of course not. This would be almost impossibly difficult to write much less maintain for all of the various OS's C++ is used on.

Comment: I need only for windows, specially windows 7

Comment: You just use `RegQueryValue`.